# Error accessing WinRT sensors in C++ desktop application

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cx

I am trying to access the WinRT sensors from a Win32 desktop application using C++/CX as mentioned here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-winrt-apis-from-desktop-applications

When I include the C++/CX header file it causes an error when building the Win32 project.

Exact error text: "error C1190: managed targeted code requires a '/clr' option."

Since I am not using /clr code at all, this is a confusing error.

Any suggestions?  Please educate me if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Which C++/CX header file are you including? You should be `#using` winmd libraries, rather than `#include`ing headers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So, in my C++/CX file I am `#using` winmd but in the pre-existing code I am `#include` ing the C++/CX class.  This is where the error occurs.

Comment: See my other question on this topic that was downvoted for no apparent reason.  It includes some of the code: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194893/consume-c-cx-winrt-dll-from-existing-pre-net-c-desktop-app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194893/consume-c-cx-winrt-dll-from-existing-pre-net-c-desktop-app)

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because you are compiling some files without /ZW option for compiler. Since you are able compile at least some files with WinRT extensions, but not others, your project configuration is inconsistent.

The option /ZW (enable WinRT extensions) has to be configured on the level of project (and not on the level of individual files). There are two ways to ensure your settings are consistent. First method is through UI in Visual Studio -- you have to go through all platforms/configurations on the project and ensure /ZW is enabled, then got through all indivudual .cpp files, and ensure they don't override project level settings. This is tedious and error prone. The easier method is to open .vcxproj in notepad and do the following:

1. Add this section at the beginnig of the file, under root Project node:

   `<ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <CompileAsWinRT>true</CompileAsWinRT>
    </ClCompile>
   </ItemDefinitionGroup>`
2. Search and remove any other places where `<CompileAsWinRT>` is defined.